# $("value") is null -> jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I am trying to implement client side validation using [jquery form validator](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/) but I have followed the guide and also noted in googling the answer to my question that there can be clashes with `prototype.js`  I have added the line `var JQuery = jQuery.noConflict();` into the bottom of my `jquery-1.5.1.min.js` file.

Firebug is still saying 
`$("#contact") is null
$("#contact").validationEngine();`

I have the required javascript and jQuery code loaded into my main page `template.php file` witch then calls a `view` called contact.

**Contact Page View**:

```
 <section id="content" class="contact-us">
        <h1>Contact</h1>

<div id ="formLayout" class="contactForm">

<section id = "validation"></section>

<form action=contact" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" id="contact" name="contact">

<fieldset>

<label><label for="name">Name:</label><span class="small">Required Field - Text</span></label>

<input type="text" name="name" value="" id="name" class="validate[required[custom[onlyLetterSp]]]"  />

<div id="error"></div>

<label><label for="email">Email:</label><span class="small">Required Field - yourname@example.com</span></label>

<input type="text" name="email" value="" id="email" class="validate[required[custom[onlyLetterSp]]]"  />

<div id="error"></div>

<label><label for="phone">Phone:</label><span class="small">Required Field - 021214589</span></label>

<input type="text" name="phone" value="" id="phone" class="validate[required[custom[onlyLetterSp]]]"  />

<div id="error"></div>

<label><label for="message">Message:</label><span class="small">Required Field - Text</span></label>

<textarea name="message" cols="90" rows="12" id="message" class="validate[required[custom[onlyLetterSp]]]" >

</textarea><div id="error"></div>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"  />

</fieldset>

</form>

</div>  

    </section>
</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <footer>&copy; Housemovers LTD 2011</footer>

    </div> <!-- Wrapper Close -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jesse.mckenzie.natcoll.net.nz/_Assignments/Industry/includes/js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/includes/js/lightbox/prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/includes/js/lightbox/scriptaculous.js?load=effects,builder" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/includes/js/lightbox/lightbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="includes/js/jquery.validationEngine-en.js"type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/includes/js/jquery.validationEngine.js"type="text/javascript"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript"> 
     JQuery(document).ready(function(){
      $("#contact").validationEngine();
       });
    </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change it to

```
jQuery("#contact")
```

the `.noConflict()` removes the `$` binding to jQuery

Answer (score 2):

If you have...

```
var JQuery = jQuery.noConflict();
```

...then...

> $("#contact") is null $("#contact").validationEngine();

...will always be the case, as `$` doesn't point to jQuery anymore. Try `jQuery` or `JQuery` there.

The latter one only works because you assigned the new identifier of jQuery to `JQuery`. I wouldn't bother doing that personally, as `jQuery` is consistent and your different case version will probably only lead to confusion.